# yii2 как передать параметр моделе

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет. Возникла проблема. 
Как с контроллера передать массив в модель?
Облазил весь google и не смог найти решение. Спасибо.

Comment: Доброе утро. Мало информации, уточните, пожалуйста, свой вопрос. Покажите свой код.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function actionTest(){
    $model = new Bar();
    $model->myCustomArray = [1,1,1,1];
    var_dump($model->myCustomArray);exit;
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо! очень помогли!